# C++ array creation problem specific to gcc 4.5

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, new-operator

The following code works under gcc versions 2.9 through 4.4 but not version 4.5:

```
 struct Pass {
 };

 int main(void){
 Pass **passes = new ( Pass (*[ 10 ]) );
 }
```

The specific error message with gcc 4.5 is:

```
prob.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
prob.cc:6:31: warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x
prob.cc:6:38: error: no matching function for call to ‘Pass::Pass(void (&)())’
prob.cc:2:1: note: candidates are: Pass::Pass()
prob.cc:2:1: note:                 Pass::Pass(const Pass&)
```

Adding the requested flag silences the initial warning but does not fix the issue. Could someone explain how to fix this?  This is from some obscure piece of C++ code I'm maintaining and I know only a limited amount of C++.

Comment: vector<Pass*> passes (10);  Or don't specify an initial size (still call reserve if you like).

Comment: @Fred, `vector` is fantastic for new code and I would recommend it wholeheartedly, but in this specific case of working code being modified by someone who doesn't understand it well I'm afraid it's the wrong answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom: There's a reason it was a comment instead of an answer. :) But vector (esp. with its contiguity requirement) is often a drop-in replacement for new[]/delete[] with minimal local changes.

Comment: See http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46159

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Pass** passes = new Pass*[10];
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this will do it:

```
typedef Pass * PassPtr;
Pass **passes = new PassPtr[10];
```

Comment: Yes, but unless you have a *really* good reason to do this, **don't** [use typedef to "hide" pointer types].

Comment: @eq, someone who "know[s] only a limited amount of C++" might be a really good reason - the typedef breaks down the expression and makes it a lot easier to understand. Especially if the typedef and the use of it are adjacent lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you are trying to wrap it so much.

```
Pass** passes = new Pass*[10];
```

Does that not work?

Comment: It does.  I'm not sure why the original author of this code made it so much more complicated that this, but thanks everyone for the quick fix.

Answer (score 1):

The extraneous parentheses you are using is now making it seem to the compiler like you are passing a constructor of Pass a lambda as a parameter. Lambdas are a new addition in C++0x, which would be why this error only cropped up in the new compiler. You can fix it by using `Pass** passes = new Pass*[10];` instead.