# Precendence rules and lambda expressions

Tags: gcc, lambda, c++11

I am trying to understand the difference in warning gives by gcc-4.3.2 and
gcc-4.5.1.

Given

```
struct S { };

int main() {
  int** i;
  i = new  int*[10] ; delete[] i; // [1a]
  i = new (int*[10]); delete[] i; // [1b]

  S** s;
  s = new  S*[10];   // [2a] fine
  s = new (S*[10]); // [2b] warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x
}
```

I understand that `[1a]` and `[2a]` correctly initialize a dynamic array of
pointers with the pointers being uninitialized.

We have instances of `[2b]` in our codebase where somebody actually wanted
`[2a]`. With the better C++0x support in gcc-4.5.1 `[2b]` suddenly triggers a
warning.

My question is, what would `[2b]` actually do in C++0x? And what is the
difference to `[1b]` which appears fine in gcc-4.5.1? Was `[2b]` doing the
correct thing with gcc-4.3.2 and C++03?

PS. I know of STL containers.

Comment: PPS. Suggestions for a better title warmly welcome.

Comment: Very interesting, I didn't know you could even *write* 1b and 2b. It looks like an incomplete placement syntax to me... is this at all valid?

Comment: @Kerrek: My fuzzy understanding of the standard was that `int*[10]` names a type so that the brackets in `[1b]` and `[2b]` don't add anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ array creation problem specific to gcc 4.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925647/c-array-creation-problem-specific-to-gcc-4-5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is a bug: the expression cannot be mistaken as a lambda expression; It would do the same thing with --std=c++0x defined.

See also

- http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46159
- [C++ array creation problem specific to gcc 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925647/c-array-creation-problem-specific-to-gcc-4-5)

I tested with gcc v 4.3,4.4,4.5 and 4.6. Only 4.5 gives the rogue warning, 4.6 happily compiles the code without complaint.

**Edit:** exact versions tested

- gcc version 4.3.5 (Ubuntu 4.3.5-3ubuntu1)
- gcc version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5)
- gcc version 4.5.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.1-7ubuntu2) **warns**
- gcc version 4.6.1 20110604 (prerelease) (Debian 4.6.0-11)

**Update** I just proved that the compiled output of the 4.5.1 compiler (and all of the other versions, for that matter) is exactly identical whether or not you specified `--std=c++0x` on the command line by doing

```
g++ -o 5-0x.s --std=c++0x -S test.cpp
g++ -o 5.s    -S             test.cpp
```

Comparing `5-0x.s` and `5.s` shows no difference whatsoever.